# Travis-ci windows meson+ninja build install (python is broken)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, travis-ci, ninja

I would like to ask for some help about travis.yml:

- I would like to set a build machine with Windows, and install Ninja + Meson as a build system. For this I need python 3 and pip3. I try to install it, but python3 and pip3 commands are not in my path - as it's seems to not to be.

My travis.yml file is here, the windows part is commented:

https://github.com/mezeipetister/game_battle/blob/master/.travis.yml

The windows part is:

```
- name: "Windows - CLANG"
    os: windows
    compiler: clang
    before_install:
        choco install python
        python -m pip install -U pip
        choco install ninja
        python -m pip install meson
```

Could you help me with this?

My main goal is to have meson and ninja installed, and meson and ninja command to work to run my `meson builddir` and `ninja -C builddir` commands.

My strategy was to somehow setup python3 and pip3, install meson with it, and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this problem myself, and found that the answer is to use choco's `--version` to grab a specific version of Python 3, and use get-pip.py instead for pip:

```
wget --progress=dot:mega https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
wget --progress=dot:mega https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.9.0/ninja-win.zip
choco install python --version 3.6.8
python get-pip.py
pip3 install meson
mkdir /c/tools/ninja-build
7z x -oC:\\tools\\ninja-build ninja-win.zip
rm get-pip.py ninja-win.zip
```

This also deals with the choco ninja being super out of date. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to construct a working $PATH.

I have had this working reliably on Travis for some time now.

Comment: Addendum: The owner of the python chocolatey package has just pushed a 3.8 beta up, and is removing their 3.6.8 package. Stable now appears to be 3.7.4